# Determining frequency of self-drive piezo oscillator circuit

Tags: oscillator, piezo

I have the circuit below, and I am wondering how the resistors and capacitor alter / determine the frequency that the piezo element vibrates at. I am assuming that they make a difference but I can't find any information pointing me in the right direction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0PuN6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the values currently there were given and no explanation as to why they are so. Any guidance as to what controls the frequency of the oscillation would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
That datasheet / catalogue for the piezo can be found [here](http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/sound/p37e.ashx).
Additionally, the product page with more specifics is [here](http://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/productdetail?partno=7BB-35-3C).

I don't know what properties play a part in this calculation so any guidance in this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a starting point: http://www.electro-tech-online.com/attachments/cmos_oscillator_761-png.7103/

Comment: @Andyaka Well it certainly knowing that is called a CMOS oscillator! But would the case of R2 << R1 be valid in this case as it's only just under half? Also, does the feedback of the piezo not play a part in it at all?

Comment: I just fed you a starting point. Without a data sheet for the three terminal device you have in your picture it's guesswork.

Comment: @Andyaka I have added datasheet and links to the question.

Comment: Not much to go on realistically - not enough information to model in a sim I'd say.

Comment: @Andyaka So I guess there isn't a general formula that accounts for the various properties and values then?

Comment: I'm not an expert on piezo devices especially those with 3 terminals. If a model can be found for the piezo then yes, you could work at it but at the moment, the piezo with 3 terminals is just a black box to me.

Answer (score 1):

This type of piezo devices are made for building sounders with minimum extra parts. They have appeared about 45 years ago when one transistor and a couple of resistors were the maximal affordable extra parts. The frequency is determined by the mechanical resonance of the piezo element, it can be forced off very little from that frequency by adding more parts, say a capacitor.

No possiblities to estimate the frequency of your circuit without a reasonably accurate math model of the piezo part, if you need something more fine than piezo manufacturer's statement 2kHz with 0,5kHz tolerance.